# Looping SQL Script with Multiple Select Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very specific problem relating to a query I am trying to write.

Basically the inventory table has about 450,000 rows of inventory items, showing the closing balance of each item of inventory for the end of each month. The other tables include a shipping table, which tracks daily data for all items of inventory coming in and leaving a specific location. Then we also have a production table, that tracks items of inventories that are used in the production process daily.

We are trying to create another table that tracks Weekly Inventories using the Shipping and Production Tables, and then calculating an end of month variance.

Here is my Pseudocode for the script I have had to write:

```
FOR EACH ROW IN INVENTORY_TABLE


    @incoming_shipping = SELECT INCOMING_AMOUNT FROM SHIPPING_TABLE WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = 1
    @outgoing_shipping = SELECT OUTGOING_AMOUNT FROM SHIPPING_TABLE WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = 1
    @outgoing_production =SELECT OUTGOING_AMOUNT FROM PRODUCTION TABLE WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = 1

    @closing_inventory=ROW.OpeningAmount + @incoming_shipping - @outgoing_shipping + @outgoing_production

    INSERT INTO WEEKLY_INVENTORY (Opening_Amount,Closing_Amount)
    'Compute Week 2 Value
    @incoming_shipping = SELECT INCOMING_AMOUNT FROM SHIPPING_TABLE WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = 2
    @outgoing_shipping = SELECT OUTGOING_AMOUNT FROM SHIPPING_TABLE WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = 2
    @outgoing_production =SELECT OUTGOING_AMOUNT FROM PRODUCTION TABLE WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = 2

    @closing_inventory=ROW.OpeningAmount + @incoming_shipping - @outgoing_shipping + @outgoing_production
    INSERT INTO WEEKLY_INVENTORY (Opening_Amount,Closing_Amount)

    'Continue doing this for the Four, Maybe 5 weeks that occur in a month.
NEXT
```

While it is correct, the query is a nightmare to execute and currently runs approximately 100 rows a minute. I have tried using Loops without Cursors, Cursors etc. and there is no obvious performance difference. I am wondering if there is a better way to write the script without using any Loops.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What values need to go into Opening_Amount and Closing_Amount columns? `@incoming_Shipping` and `@closing_inventory`? An example (from start to finish) on some sample data would really help.

Comment: If you are using e.g. C# I would try to read all the data I want by calling a sproc then perform all querying and calc required using in memory based operations. Finally store the resulting data table using a sproc that has a table-valued parameter.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos It might be a solution, but I don't think it's necessary to overload "the application" with processing this, since it could be done directly in the DB. (Imagine network overhead for transferring the data to and from the application / / increased memory usage for holding 450k rows / increased CPU usage for processing etc.) which could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something in the lines of would work for you:

```
INSERT INTO WEEKLY_INVENTORY(Opening_Amount, Closing_Amount)
SELECT
   OPENING_AMOUNT,
   (OPENING_AMOUNT + 
     (SELECT INCOMING_AMOUNT 
      FROM SHIPPING_TABLE 
      WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = ST.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
   ) - (
        (SELECT OUTGOING_AMOUNT 
         FROM SHIPPING TABLE 
         WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = ST.WEEK_OF_MONTH) + 
        (SELECT OUTGOING_AMOUNT 
         FROM PRODUCTION_TABLE 
         WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = ST.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
     )
FROM SHIPPING_TABLE ST
WHERE ST.WEEK_OF_MONTH <= 5
```

You don't have to loop over all rows in order to do this. You can calculate for each `WEEK_OF_MONTH` the value that needs to be inserted into `WEEKLY_INVENTORY` by using a combination of `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

In the `SELECT` part you build the values, for each week of month by using other SELECT statements to determine the value for Closing_Amount.

The above query would be a straightforward option from your code, but the same functionality as above can be achieved, with an increase in speed by using a `JOIN`, with the below query:

```
INSERT INTO WEEKLY_INVENTORY(Opening_Amount, Closing_Amount)
SELECT
  ST.OPENING_AMOUNT
  , (ST.OPENING_AMOUNT + ST.INCOMING_AMOUNT)-(ST.OUTGOING_AMOUNT + PT.OUTGOING_AMOUNT)
FROM SHIPPING_TABLE ST
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTION_TABLE PT ON ST.WEEK_OF_MONTH = PT.WEEK_OF_MONTH
```

Depending on how your database schema is structured, the queries above might not work as you might need to use an aggregate function, `SUM()` I assume and also GROUPing BY product. But using just the pseudocode you provided, this is the translation into SQL.

Comment: Exactly what I needed - a fresh pair of eyes. Looking at the code, it all makes sense and I can tinker with it to make it work. Not sure about the SUM vs. +/- will let you know how I get on and post the result

Comment: @AnthonyWood If you manage to run the query and if the solution has worked for you please do not forget to upvote/mark the answer as correct so others that find this post will know that it will be helpful.